# Failed to add a WCF Data service 'Service Reference' for an OData consumption C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, odata, wcf-data-services

Every thing is OK if I add  a WCF Data service 'Service Reference' for an OData consumption C# application which is against .net 4.5.

Now I need my OData consumption C# application run against .net 3.5. So I created a .net 3.5 c# application, and trying to add the same 'Service Reference' in the same way, Visual Studio give me an error:

```
The Custom Tool 'DataServiceCoreClientGenerator' failed. Data Service client 
code generation failed:

The element 'DataService' has an attribute 'DataServiceVersion' with an 
unrecognized version '3.0'
```

For OData consumption project, do I have to use .net 4.5? Or it depends on the server side WCF Data service?

Answer (score 1):

Well ...
This is a common issue with specific versions of tools used by specific versions of VS.
Sometimes You just have to go beyond :).
So either You have access to VS 2008 and You can open that project and create client code or... you can create Your classes manually like [this article describes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756369%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). VS is doing exactly the same underneath but is using a newer version.

I am not sure this will work though if Your server is 4.5.